# How to make android box device recognised as mobile device, and not tv device with build.prop

Tags: android-versions, build.prop

I want to use an application for mobile devices on my android box. I am using X96 Max+, and when I install an app, the version for android tv-s gets installed, and I want to have a version for android phone devices. If I directly download the version for mobile devices, the warning goes off and says "This application can't be used on a non-mobile device!".
Box uses android version 9, so I tried to edit `build.prop` file (the device is rooted), and set `ro.product.brand` and `ro.product.model` to google pixel 2 I think. And nothing happens.
If I go in setting and about, I can see that these properties have been changed.

So my question is, how can I know which parameters the app inspects before installation/launch and how to find what to edit to make it work.

Comment: Idk but android.software.leanback may give you right direction (have a similar follow-up question)

Comment: I am not developing that app, I just have the apk.

Comment: You can know what the app is doing by decompiling it, e.g. using [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) (assuming that the check is done in Java code and not in native assembler code). Inspecting the Java source code of course requires a bit of Java and Android development knowledge.

Comment: I am trying to access the manifest file with [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), not sure will it help, but will give it a try to Jadx soon.

Comment: Where does the warning *"This application can't be used on a non-mobile device"* come from, it looks like browser notification to me? Are we talking about already downloaded apk?

Comment: Installation is no problem, the warning pops when I launch the app. And then the app closes automatically after I dismiss the warning.